# ADO .Net RESTful partial update

Tags: rest, ado.net

I'm using a very undocumented RESTful ADO .Net service. I am trying to perform a partial update (as in, just send through the data that has changed).

My current request looks like this:

```
PUT https://{URL}/JobTypeMs(37294)
Headers: 
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json

Body:
{ 
     "Jobtype_Name" : "Completed 2", 
     "Tenant_Id": "{A Long ID}",
     "Job_Color_Code": "000000"
}
```

What this does, is "null"/false/blank everything that I do not send through (Status and a few other columns). How do I avoid this?

Or will I be forced to do a GET request before every update to get the current columns and then change everything?

NOTE: I've never used ADO .Net before and I do not have access to the ADO .Net service to make changes to it. I can only utilize the RESTful interface. I am also not sure if this is a problem with this particular implementation of ADO .Net or if it is standard.

UPDATE: As adrift suggested, this service does not support the PATCH method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and see if the service supports [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> Several applications extending the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
> require a feature to do partial resource modification.  The existing
> HTTP PUT method only allows a complete replacement of a document.
> This proposal adds a new HTTP method, PATCH, to modify an existing
> HTTP resource.

See also [this page](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/) at The RESTful Cookbook.

If the service does not support `PATCH`, then (as you mentioned) you will have to first `GET` the resource and then `PUT` the modified values.

As a side note, the behavior of this service isn't dependent on ADO.NET or any other technology.  Any development stack could be used on the server and implemented in the same way.

Comment: The server responded with "Method Not Allowed". So unfortunately PATCH isn't the way :/. If ADO .Net isn't dictating the behavior for this server, what is? (ADO .Net seems fairly specific). Or are you talking about REST as a concept isn't tied to ADO?

Comment: It's how the service method has been written.  Using any server side stack (ADO.NET, Node.js, PHP) you could write the method to accept input for a `PUT` and treat it this way.  In fact, the documentation for the `PATCH` proposal indicates that this is the correct behavior.  ADO.NET, is a data access technology, and "out of the box" doesn't implement anything needed for a web service.

Comment: Ah ok that's fair enough. Well if you think of any other possible solution I'd love to hear it, although the current one works, it's quite slow (this particular API takes 5+ seconds per API call, so the GET+PUT takes over 10 seconds... Not ideal for anyone)